# Writing FILE* through pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, file-pointer

I have two file open in two different processes. There's a pipe connecting the two. Is it possible to write directly from one file to another? Especially if the process reading doesn't know the size of the file it's trying to read?

I was hoping to do something like this

```
#define length 100
int main(){
  int frk = fork();
  int pip[2];
  pipe(pip);
  if (frk==0){ //child
    FILE* fp fopen("file1", "r");
    write(pip[1],fp,length);
  }
  else {
    FILE* fp fopen("file2", "w");
    read(pip[0],fp,length);
}
```

Comment: `pipe(pip);` should be before the `fork();`.

Comment: Is it impossible to create a pipe after forking?

Comment: With the `pipe` function, yes. Also you are using `write` and `read` wrong, the second parameter is the buffer, not a pointer to a `FILE`. and you forgot the `=` after `FILE* fp`.

Comment: You can create a pipe at any time, but in a case like yours it's only *useful* to do it before the fork, because only that way do parent and child share the same one.

Comment: @Mikkelbruun, not, it's not impossible... but if you do the `pipe(2)` after forking, you'll get two pipe descriptors in each process (four in total), without any relation to each other (between pipes).... the trick of piping before fork is to use one of the descriptors in the parent process and the other in the child....  for that, the `pipe(2)` call must be done in the common part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to write directly from one file to another?

C does not provide any mechanism for that, and it seems like it would require specialized hardware support.  The standard I/O paradigm is that data get read from their source into memory or written from memory to their destination.  That pesky "memory" in the middle means copying from one file to another cannot be direct.

Of course, you can write a function or program that performs such a copy, hiding the details from you.  This is what the `cp` command does, after all,  but the C standard library does not contain a function for that purpose.

> Especially if the process reading doesn't know the size of the file it's trying to read?

That bit isn't very important.  One simply reads and then writes (only) what one has read, repeating until there is nothing more to read.  "Nothing more to read" means that a read attempt indicates by its return value that the end of the file has been reached.

If you want one process to read one file and the other to write that data to another file, using a pipe to convey data between the two, then you need both processes to implement that pattern.  One reads from the source file and writes to the pipe, and the other reads from the pipe and writes to the destination file.

Special note: for the process reading from the pipe to detect EOF on that pipe, the other end has to be closed, in both processes.  After the fork, each process can and should close the pipe end that it doesn't intend to use.  The one using the write end then closes that end when it has nothing more to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

In other unix systems, like BSD, there's a call to connect directly two file descriptors to do what you want, but don't know if there's a system call to do that in linux.  Anywya, this cannot be done with `FILE *` descriptors, as these are the *instance of a buffered file* used by `<stdio.h>` library to represent a file.  You can get the file descriptor (as the system knows it) of a `FILE *` instance by  a call to the `getfd(3)` function call.

The semantics you are trying to get from the system are quite elaborate, as you want something to pass directly the data from one file descriptor to another, without intervention of any process (directly in the kernel), and the kernel needs for that a pool of threads to do the work of copying directly from the read calls to the write ones.

The old way of doing this is to create a thread that makes the work of reading from one file descriptor (not a `FILE *` pointer) and write to the other.

Another thing to comment is that the `pipe(2)` system call gives you two *connected* descriptors, that allow you to `read(2)` in one (the `0` index) what is `write(2)`n in the second (the `1` index).  If you `fork(2)` a second process, and you do the `pipe(2)` call on both, you will have two pipes (with two descriptors each), one in each process, with no relationship between them.  You will be able only to communicate each process with itself, but not with the other (which doesn't know anything about the other process' pipe descriptors) so no communication between them will be possible.

Next is a complete example of what you try to do:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define length 100

#define FMT(fmt) "pid=%d:"__FILE__":%d:%s: " fmt, getpid(), __LINE__, __func__
#define ERR(fmt, ...) do {                  \
             fprintf(stderr,                     \
                     FMT(fmt ": %s (errno = %d)\n"), \
                     ##__VA_ARGS__,                  \
                     strerror(errno), errno);        \
             exit(1);                            \
        } while(0)

void copy(int fdi, int fdo)
{
    unsigned char buffer[length];
    ssize_t res, nread;

    while((nread = res = read(fdi, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0) {
        res = write(fdo, buffer, nread);
        if (res < 0) ERR("write");
    } /* while */
    if (res < 0) ERR("read");
} /* copy */

int main()
{
    int pip[2];
    int res;

    res = pipe(pip);
    if (res < 0) ERR("pipe");

    char *filename;

    switch (res = fork()) {
    case -1: /* error */
         ERR("fork");

    case 0:  /* child */
         filename = "file1";
         res = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
         if (res < 0) ERR("open \"%s\"", filename);
         close(pip[0]);
         copy(res, pip[1]);
         break;

    default: /* parent, we got the child's pid in res */
         filename = "file2";
         res = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0666);
         if (res < 0) ERR("open \"%s\"", filename);
         close(pip[1]);
         copy(pip[0], res);
         int status;
         res = wait(&status); /* wait for the child to finish */
         if (res < 0) ERR("wait");
         fprintf(stderr,
                 FMT("The child %d finished with exit code %d\n"),
                 res,
                 status);
         break;
    } /* switch */
    exit(0);
} /* main */
```